# How can I set a custom log4j properties file in DEV mode in Play! Framework?

Tags: logging, configuration, playframework, log4j, playframework-1.x

I have a log4j.properties with production spesific log settings:

```
log4j.appender.Rolling.File=${catalina.home}/logs/thelog.log
```

But this does not work any good localhost. I have tried to set a different log file if in DEV mode without luck:

```
%dev.application.log.path=/log4j_local.properties
```

It seems that this application settings is not applied if I have the log4j.properties file in the conf folder.

Is there a way to have different logging settings in PROD and DEV mode?

Answer (score 1):

```
%test.application.log.path=/log4j.test.properties
```

and put the contents into yourprojectroot/conf/log4j.test.properties

Answer (score 0):

The logger configuration file path can be overridden when launching the server, as described here : 
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/SettingsLogger

Hope it helps.
Regards,

Comment: The link is for Play2 but the author asks for Play1 (tagged with play framework-1.x).